# Is it possible to record a copy of sent system workflow message emails as activities?

Tags: email, system-workflow-messages

Is there a way to do this, or an extension that offers it?

We want to be able to see what was sent to people when one of these was used.

Comment: Does https://civicrm.org/extensions/transactional-emails do what you want?

Comment: @Aidan yep, looks like it, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We built this extension to help with this scenario: https://github.com/fuzionnz/nz.co.fuzion.transactional

> This extension adds bounce handling and click tracking, and creates activities for CiviCRM's transactional emails (i.e event registrations, contribution receipts, invoices, scheduled reminders, and so on).

> Out of the box, CiviCRM only does the things mentioned above when sending via CiviMail. This extension adds that functionality to all mail sent from CiviCRM.